# How many boys are there in the village?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, ratio

There are 180 people in a village among them there are twice as many girls as there are boys and there are twice as many men as there are children and there are twice as many women as there are men

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! We usually ask people to contribute what they have tried before helping them to avoid solving other people's homework. What have you done so far? Please show your work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let no of boys be $x$, so number of girls is $2x$, so no of children is $3x$, so number of men will be $6x$ and no of women will be $12x$.
Total number of people = $12x+6x+3x = 21x$ (Both Adults and Children)($x=180/21 = 8.57$).
Total number of people  $12x+6x=18x$ (Only adults) ($x=180/18 = 10$).